# How do I print a vector in the title of a graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have built a function which pulls in values provided by an end user and produces a graph as a result.

The user has the option to provide a `site`, which can be either a single value or multiple:

```
myFunction(sd, ed, site = NULL){}
```

Note that I verify the presence of `site` by:

```
if(!is.null(site)){
    combi <-
      combi %>%
      filter(siteLocation %in% site)
  }
```

When a user runs it, they can call:

```
myFunction("2021-01-01", "2021-01-10", "site1")
```

or

```
myFunction("2021-01-01", "2021-01-10", c("site1", "site2", "site3"))
```

I have set the graph that is produced to display the name of the site which works if a single value is passed, but if multiple values are passed, it only displays the first element.

How can I get it to display the full vector (every element) in the title?

Graph code:

```
print(ggplot(combi) +
    aes(appDTS, n, fill = siteLocation) +
    geom_col() +
    scale_x_datetime(date_labels = "%d-%b-%Y", date_breaks  = "1 day") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
      labs(title = paste0("Appointments (", site, ")"),
           subtitle = paste0("Dates: ", sd, " to ", ed),
           x = "Date", y = "Appointments")
```

Comment: Please add this as an answer as it has more value than a mere comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sprintf` and `toString` :

```
title = sprintf('Appointments (%s)', toString(site))
```

Comment: I like the elegance of this solution. I would also like to know if the title could display `Appointments (all sites)` if the `site` argument is left blank; can this be achieved?

Comment: That would require checking with `if` before plotting. `if(site == '') site = 'all sites'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `paste` with collapse should provide you what you want.

```
paste("Appointments (", paste(site, collapse = ", "), ")")
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify `myFunction` to take or return the `site` argument as a vector

```
c("2021-01-01", "2021-01-10", c("site1", "site2", "site3"))
```

assuming that your intent is to create any number of `site1 ... siten` as the `site` argument to title to represent that many objects as a single string.